# React event delegation from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, gatsby

I have a Gatsby `Link` element inside of an `<li>` and I want the `Link` element to be triggered if the `<li>` is clicked with cursor or hit with the `enter` key.

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    ...Constructor...
    render() {
        ...DOM elements...
        <input type="text" value={this.state.query} onChange={this.search} placeholder={'Search'} />
        {this.state.results.map((page, index) => (
            <li tabIndex={index} key={page.id} >
               <Link to={"/" + page.path}>{page.title}</Link>
            </li>
        ))}
        ...DOM elements...
    }
    ...More functions...
}
```

The above code is inside of a `render` block, which is inside of a class which extends `Component`.

I've tried adding an `onClickHandler` to the `<li>`, but don't know of any object I can pass to it which contains a reference to its child...

The main reason I need the event delegation to the child is because the `tabIndex` (which receives focus from the `input` element above it) only works on the `<li>`, so once the `<li>` has focus, I want the user to be able to hit enter and have that event propogate to the child `<Link>` element (which is a special link element using Gatsby's internal routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the current `page.path` as well as the event directly to your handler, `onKeyPress={e => this.goTo(e, page.path)}`.

Example.

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

export default class Search extends Component {
  ... redacted for brevity ...

  goTo = (e, path) => {
    if (e.Key === "Enter") {
      navigate(`/${path}`);
    }
  };

  render() {
    ... redacted for brevity ...
    {
      this.state.results.map((page, index) => (
        <li tabIndex={index} key={page.id} onKeyPress={e => this.goTo(e, page.path)}>
          <Link to={"/" + page.path}>{page.title}</Link>
        </li>
      ));
    }
    ... redacted for brevity ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `e.Key === "Enter"` doesn't work, but the rest does! Thank you! I don't even need that `Enter` key conditional. I don't mind if any key triggers as long as tab doesn't (which it doesn't thankfully lol).

Comment: Yikes. I've wrote the key out of memory, which is probably wrong  Anyways, great that it has worked out~